# Redirect URL is not working with Vue-MSAL

Tags: javascript, vue.js, azure-ad-msal

I have a single-page VueJS app where I'm trying to use the [vue-msal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-msal) plugin to connect to the Azure Active Directory to authenticate a user before accessing the site. In my Azure app registration, I've set the platform redirect URL to be `http://localhost:8080/home/`... so upon authentication it should take me to this URL where I can see the main part of my app. However, when it does return my token, my app is then taking me back to the login page (instead of taking me to the home page). Here's how my process is currently working:

- open the webapp to `http://localhost:8080` (the main login page)
- click on the Login button which then authenticates through Azure AD
- the authentication process returns the token to the redirect URL... however, it then kicks me back to the "login" page.
- if I click the Login button again, it then takes me to the correct home page where I can see the rest of my app.

Ideally, I don't want to have to click the same button twice just to login... but I can't seem to find any setting or configuration which will not require this step. Here's how I'm setting up my authentication code:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import msal from 'vue-msal';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Login from '../views/Login.vue';
import Home from '../views/Home.vue';

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Login',
        component: Login,
    },
    {
        path: '/home',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Home,
    },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes,
});

const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        tenant: <tenantID>,
        clientId: <clientID>,
        authority:
            'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/',
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8080/home/',
        navigateToRequestUrl: false,
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage', // This configures where your cache will be stored
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge
        secureCookies: false,
    },
    system: {
        loggerOptions: {
            loggerCallback: (level, message, containsPii) => {
                if (containsPii) {
                    return;
                }
                switch (level) {
                    case msal.LogLevel.Error:
                        console.error(message);
                        return;
                    case msal.LogLevel.Info:
                        console.info(message);
                        return;
                    case msal.LogLevel.Verbose:
                        console.debug(message);
                        return;
                    case msal.LogLevel.Warning:
                        console.warn(message);
                }
                false;
            },
            windowHashTimeout: 60000,
            iframeHashTimeout: 6000,
            loadFrameTimeout: 0,
            asyncPopups: false,
        },
    },
    framework: { globalMixin: true },
};

Vue.use(msal, msalConfig);
Vue.use(VueRouter);

export default router;
```

And then on my Login.vue component, I have the following code which gets called when the user clicks on the login button:

```
<script>
export default {
    name: 'Login',
    methods: {
        login() {
            if (!this.$msal.isAuthenticated()) {
                this.$msal.signIn();
            } 
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: A wild guess is to set `cacheLocation: 'localStorage'`. So that it persists the cache after the redirect.

Comment: Hmm... this does seem to fix the issue a little bit. I also changed `storeAuthStateInCookie: 'true'`... However, it only works after you've had to "double-click" on the login button the first time to write the auth settings to the cookie. After that it works... but the first time still requires the double-click.